# Read the docs: Build environment creation failed

Tags: read-the-docs

Read The Docs kept telling me that my documents failed to build. Error log shows that 'Build environment creation failed'. I tried to wipe my build environment, but the documents still failed to build.

Here's an image of the page:

[Build environment creation failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsU7a.png)

I have read the [Frequently Asked Questions](http://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html), but it doesn't contain any information about my issue. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received the same error.

In my case, I had to disable EPUB build. You can try this.

1. Go to your readthedoc projects `Admin` settings.
2. Then `Advanced Settings`
3. Then, under `Enable EPUB build`,make sure the checkbox is unticked. Do the same for `Enable PDF build`.

See if one of those two might be the cause of the error.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :) I've found a related issue on GitHub and this issue is resolved. https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/issues/2329

Comment: Thanks for letting me know!